# How to redirect a sub-directory to the root

Tags: apache-2.4

I have Apache running for a Joomla! site
The site is CBSL, under www (so www\cbsl\index.php)
To access it my user have to code http:\mysite\cbsl
Is there a way to configure Apache so that http:\mysite is sufficient ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/208197/apache-rewrite-or-redirect

Answer (score 3):

You simply had to use a correct value for the "DocumentRoot" directive. In this case, setting it to "root_path\www\cbsl" should be sufficient.